# Ruby - Split file line into array with index in array name

Tags: arrays, ruby, file

This is a very specific question (which I doubt most will be able to benefit from) but I'll explain:

I have an example file which contains numbers split by commas on each line:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
abcdefg
1.3.4
```

I want to be able to split the file into lines (easily done):

```
file = File.open(filename)
file = file.read.split("\n")
```

And now I want to split each line into an array if it includes "," and have the name or the array be something like: 1array (with 1 being the file line index)

Something like this would be preferable:

```
file.each_with_index |c, i| do # c=content, i=index
  if c.include? ","
    instance_array_set("@#{i}array", c.split(","))
  end
end
```

I've looked everywhere for anything on an instance array concept but I can't seem to find anything. I am open to completely different ways of doing what I'm trying to do (as long as it's not too long).

Thanks in advance (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

Variables' identifiers can't start with a digit so I move it to the end of the name

```
File.open(filename).read.split("\n").each_with_index do |item, index|
  if item.include?(",")
    instance_variable_set("@array#{index}", item.split(","))
  end
end
```

Comment: So instance variables don't need to be single variables? They can be arrays as well?

Comment: of course. they are just names. you can assign anything to a variable

Comment: Now I think about it, that makes a whole lot of sense. Thanks. Also, how would I go about calling one of the instance variables that I don't know the name of? For example: `array1 = 1  array2 = 2  array3 = 3    i=1`         Could I call array1 like this?:  `array#{i} = 1+1`

Comment: Well, you're right. In fact, I don't know why you prefer set instance variables rather then have a result array with every array who pass the test in it. So that you can iterate it, take a random array from it or do whatever you want to

Comment: Why do you think you need to set instance variables? You could just have a variable with all the array that pass your `include?(",")` test in it. In your case would be `[["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"]]`

Comment: I don't necessarily need instance variables. I just guess it would be easier to get information from them.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Found out I can use `instance_variable_get("@array#{i}")`

Comment: Consider using [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to avoid the creation of a temporary array: `File.foreach(fname).with_index { |line,i| instance_variable_set("@array#{index}", line.chomp.split(",")) }`.

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of arrays:

```
result =
  File.readlines('/tmp/input').map do |line|
    values = line.chomp.split(',')
    values if values.size >= 2
  end.compact

result[0][2]
#⇒ "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version:

```
File.readlines(filename).select{ |e| e.split("").include? "," }.map{ |e| e.chomp.split "," }

# => [["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"], ["11", "12", "13"]]
```